# Biological Image Sharpening/Processing

Tags: image-quality, image-processing

I am working on a bachelors thesis on electron irradiation of horse tendons. As part of the thesis I have to take measurement readings from images of the horse tendons taken using a [scanning electron microscope](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scanning_electron_microscope). To keep it simple I'll refer to "seeds", like seeds on a corn cob. Each strand on the attached image is made out of chains of these "seeds".

I need to take measurements of pixel lengths of these seed chains(around 10 seeds for average sake), however the images aren't sharp(see example). I would like to ask for suggestions for processing the image so that I can see the "seeds" better for identification of suitable seed chains and image measurement/processing.

I have access to GIMP so if someone could suggest functions that I could use on these images to sharpen the image I would be grateful.

[image: Example SEM Image]

Comment: If someone would like to know the image is on the scale of ~150 pixels = 1 micrometer, or 1 millionth of a meter.

Comment: specialized forum for discussing biological imaging data is https://forum.microlist.org/

Comment: For bringing out faint textural detail or small low contract features in an image with high overall contrast and hard edges, such as Cassini's Saturn system images,  my fave go-to filter is nonlinear unsharp. Unfortunately it's not built in to GIMP, Photoshop or any other tool I know of, but something I write in Python, IDL or Julia. If you can make use of one of those, I can explain further in an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The quickest way to sharpen things in modern Gimp (2.10):

- `Filters > Enhance > Wavelet decompose`
- Then duplicate/triplicate the top layers as needed (`Scale 1`, `Scale 2`)

[image]

In addition if you want to do a lot of measures of an image, something that can help:

- Use the Path tool and add anchors on the points of interest:

[image]

Then use the [`path-csv` script](http://gimp-path-tools.sourceforge.net/tools.shtml#path-csv) to export path data to a CSV:

```
,,,,,,,
Seeds,1,619.5,376.5,619.5,376.5,619.5,376.5
Seeds,1,620.0,385.5,620.0,385.5,620.0,385.5
Seeds,1,621.5,396.0,621.5,396.0,621.5,396.0
Seeds,1,622.0,403.0,622.0,403.0,622.0,403.0
Seeds,1,623.0,411.0,623.0,411.0,623.0,411.0
Seeds,1,623.0909090909091,418.1818181818182,623.0909090909091,418.1818181818182,623.0909090909091,418.1818181818182
Seeds,1,624.0,426.3636363636364,624.0,426.3636363636364,624.0,426.3636363636364
```

(contents of columns described in link above)

Answer (score 3):

If you want to sharpen your images in GIMP then look [here](https://thegimptutorials.com/how-to-sharpen-image/). As the link suggests:

> Method 1: Select the Sharpen tool from the toolbox and hand-paint the areas to be sharpened.

> Method 2: Open the Filters menu, select the Enhance submenu, and click
> Sharpen (Unsharp Mask).

Another approach would be [edge detection](https://visihow.com/Detect_Edges_in_an_Image_in_the_GIMP_Application) which highlights changes in tone.

You should play around with the settings to see what best suits your application. Understand that sharpening doesn't add information, but it may make information easier to see. For your purposes increasing contrast may help as well...